# Java - Issue with making HashMap available from Other Classes

Tags: java, hashmap

I have researched a lot for the answer to the current issue I have however, I'm not sure what is going wrong:

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Items
    {
      public static void main (String args[])
      {
      HashMap<String, Double> Hallway = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> Toilet = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> ChemistryLab = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> Outdoors = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> Library = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> Engineering = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> Cafeteria = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> ComputerLab = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> LectureTheater = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> MedicalCentre = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getHallwayItems() 
    {
      return Hallway;        
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getToiletItems() 
    {
      return Toilet;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getChemistryLabItems() 
    {
     return ChemistryLab;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getOutdoorItems() 
    {
     return Outdoors;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getLibraryItems() 
    {
     return Library;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getEngineeringItems() 
    {
     return Engineering;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getCafeteriaItems() 
    {
     return Cafeteria;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getComputerLabItems() 
    {
     return ComputerLab;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getLectureTheaterItems() 
    {
     return LectureTheater;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getMedicalCentreItems() 
    {
     return MedicalCentre;
    }

    }
```

It says that it cannot find the variable Hallway when I attempt compiling however, I don't see how this can be resolved.
Thank you for any assistance provided.

Comment: You need to learn about [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

Comment: And about standard Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hallway` is a local variable inside main function. And main is a static function too. These variables declared inside `main` cannot be accesses from other functions.

There are two alternatives,

1) Declare all the maps as static members of the objects and have static `getHallway()` static `getToilet`, etc.
2) I personally would suggest this,

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

```
public class Items
{
    private HashMap<String, Double> Hallway = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    private HashMap<String, Double> Toilet = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    ...

    public HashMap<String, Double> getHallwayItems() 
    {
       return Hallway;        
    }
    ...
    ...

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Items myItem = new Items();
         myItem.getHallwayItems(); // and do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

This way, we also exploit OOPS...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define Hallway and others as instance variable. The variables were defined in method scope which won't be accessible in other methods.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Items
{
  HashMap<String, Double> Hallway = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> Toilet = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> ChemistryLab = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> Outdoors = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> Library = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> Engineering = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> Cafeteria = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> ComputerLab = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> LectureTheater = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  HashMap<String, Double> MedicalCentre = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  public static void main (String args[])
  {

  }

public HashMap<String, Double> getHallwayItems() 
{
  return Hallway;        
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getToiletItems() 
{
  return Toilet;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getChemistryLabItems() 
{
 return ChemistryLab;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getOutdoorItems() 
{
 return Outdoors;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getLibraryItems() 
{
 return Library;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getEngineeringItems() 
{
 return Engineering;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getCafeteriaItems() 
{
 return Cafeteria;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getComputerLabItems() 
{
 return ComputerLab;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getLectureTheaterItems() 
{
 return LectureTheater;
}

public HashMap<String, Double> getMedicalCentreItems() 
{
 return MedicalCentre;
}

}
```